# Convert Java/Dynamic web project to maven project using Maven Command line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I want to convert a Java/Dynamic web project to a Maven project. I use Eclipse IDE to develop Java applications.
One of the straight forward options available to me is to use 'Convert to Maven project' in Eclipse. But there are situations where I cannot use that option since the Maven plugin doesn't work in some networks like my Work environment.
So I want to know a Maven command (on Command Line) that would help me convert my Eclipse-built Java Web App to a Maven project.

Thank you in advance, Happy learning.

Comment: Whether a project is known by Eclipse as a Maven project is stored within and managed by Eclipse.  The Maven command line knows nothing about modifying how Eclipse sees your project.

Comment: So does this mean there is no command available in Maven API to convert to a Maven project ?

Comment: No. Maven knows nothing about Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse feature "Convert to Maven Project" works on projects that already have an appropriate POM. A project that was initially created by Eclipse doesn't have that POM.

So what you must do, is simply create a POM with packaging type WAR, then put it into the root of the project.

You also have to take care of the source directories. The Maven standard way is to have all sources under these four directories:

- `src/main/java`
- `src/main/resources`
- `src/test/java`
- `src/test/resources`

Eclipse simply stores everything under `src`. So you either change your file and directory structure, or you change the appropriate `<build>` parameters in the POM. I suggest the former.

The "Convert to Maven Project" feature does more than adding the Maven nature to the Eclipse build settings. It also creates and configures the Eclipse project meta files (the files `.project` and `.classpath` and the folder `.settings`). Therefore I suggest to delete them first in your project directory, so Eclipse can start on a clean project.

Afterwards you simply can convert your project with the above mentioned feature. It should create the meta files, and - as it is a web project (packaging type WAR) - it also should add the appropriate natures that let Eclipse show the project as a web project.

Comment: Hi Seelenvirtuose, thanks for the response. But it would be great if you could help me out with a Maven command also that would convert a Java project to a Maven project using a command prompt.